# Уникальность данных 2-х столбцов

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, sqlite, phpmyadmin

Возможно ли в SQL создать (СУБД phpmyadmin) создать таблицу таким образом, чтобы  в столбце сущностей "Name_1" и "Name_2" Нельзя было создать одинаковые данные? 
То есть чтобы не было "Name_1 = Name_2"

Comment: Насколько я знаю, в последних версиях MySQL (MariaDB) ограничение CHECK уже поддерживается. Тогда нет проблем: check(name_1<>name_2)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Уточните, "Name_1 = Name_2" тут речь о значениях в одной строке или во всех строках таблицы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда говорят об уникальности 2-х столбцов, то комбинация`Name_1 = Name_2` в одной строке может иметь место, но только один раз в таблице.

Чтобы исключить какую-то комбинацию значений в строке, надо установить правило:

```
CONSTRAINT check_Names CHECK (Name_1 <> Name_2)
```